# Flagging an answer and editing the details of that answer into another answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, answers, low-quality-posts

This question refers to this review item:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17951059 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592493/displaying-pair-plot-in-pandas-data-frame/45195783#45195783).

Someone decided to flag this answer as low quality and either they or another user took it upon themselves to edit this answer into another existing answer.

My understanding is that it's a good idea to post a new answer with any updates and by posting a new answer is a positive contribution to the site.

As that review was split with 3 reviewers saying it's ok and 3 flagging for deletion. I figured we should sort out, what protocol to follow in these cases.

[image]

Is this how we should do things? Flag this type of answer as low quality and edit another answer to include the details of that answer.
Thought?

*I've pinged all the reviewers so they are aware that this review is being discussed.*

Related: [Should I edit an answer to add information that is on a comment of that answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348261/should-i-edit-an-answer-to-add-information-that-is-on-a-comment-of-that-answer)

Comment: In this instance. I'd probably add it as a new answer. They state that the original answer is now depreciated. It would be quite difficult to edit that into the answer without taking over IMO. Better to add a new one.

Comment: I don't think that editing an answer like that, should be allowed. Because the question already have a new answer with updated info, there is no need to edit the other answers to match it. Also, the new answer clearly states that this is as an update to the existing one.

Comment: I asked this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303250/should-we-let-people-know-that-their-actions-are-being-discussed-if-so-whats-t about my pinging around the site to let all the reviewers and editor know it's being discussed.

Comment: I voted for deletion under the assumption that it would then be included in the original answer as an update. Somebody coming to SO from google looking for a solution will probably only look at the first answer, and that answer needs to be up to date. But I agree there should be some kind of policy for these cases

Comment: @PiedPiper it's good to understand your reasoning

Comment: I just looked at this again. The change is very minor and when I voted the accepted answer had already been edited. So leaving the update answer makes no sense. And I think it should have been a comment on the accepted answer

Comment: Same reasoning as PiedPiper - as the original answer included the change by the time I reviewed, there didn't seem to be much point in keeping the reviewed answer. However, thinking about it now, maybe the original answer should include a something to mention the fact someone else came up with the revision? Thinking in particular of this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355765/1873567 Thanks for the heads up @YvetteColomb

Comment: @Bugs It's a 9-character edit, plus a code comment. I wouldn't call that "taking over".

Comment: @CalvT븃 "*should include something to mention the fact that someone else came up with the revision*" That's what the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42593334/revisions) is there for.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett right - but there's no current mention of Michael Szczepaniak - that's what I meant

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett I would. Just editing the answer to correct it isn't enough IMO. I'd want to state that the original answer is now depreciated and that this is the new answer so that future visitors come and go _damn that's where I was going wrong_ and actually know why rather than just blindly going that's the code, that'll do. Each to their own though. The edit you made doesn't take over. The information I'd have popped in, would have.

Comment: @Bugs Gotcha. I did add a note in the answer explaining the correction; hopefully it wasn't too invasive.

Comment: @CalvT븃 It's interesting to note that there *would* have been a mention of Michale Szczepaniak, had he suggested an edit to begin with. Which is what I think he should have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was one of the original "Recommend Deletion" voters. However, with more thought I've changed my decision, the answer should stay. Why?

**Because Stack Overflow is for everybody, not just people with the latest version of something**.

So with that in mind, I've reverted the accepted answer to have its old code, and added a notice saying it's deprecated, and a link to the newer answer below.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, I wanted to do that myself, but didn't want to push it, as I asked the question. The OP has since done a complete edit. I also pinged him about this meta post (which I should've done earlier).

Comment: What's the benefit of having this information spread out across two answers? With much duplicate code to boot? (Eek!) Why not just put it all in one convenient place, i.e. edit the existing to make it better? Can easily indicating what's valid for pandas 0.19.0 and earlier, and what's valid for pandas 0.20.0 and later. Now the newer answer just says "now deprecated". What's "now"? What if someone is using 0.19.0? Then it isn't actually deprecated. I find it very misguided that we don't just improve a fine answer, rather than duplicating much of its content into a second answer.

Comment: I totally agree with you that the answers should also work for people with older versions of software. But the solutions for the different versions should all be in the same answer

Comment: So we've come full circle: The original answer's OP did the right thing and updated his answer to include the minor code update for pandas >= 0.20.0. So now the new answer consists exclusively of redundant material, again. So... are we supposed to revert the edit on the original answer to make it out-of-date again?

Comment: @PiedPiper Unfortunately, there is no direct way to flag an answer as duplicate, short of flagging for moderator intervention, which would probably be overkill in this case. So, yeah, I guess we just let this one go. [*sigh*]

Answer (score 17):

I was the one who edited the gist of the [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195783/119775) into the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42593334/119775).

The original answer was lengthy and complete. The new one was just a small amendment to it:

```
grr = pd.scatter_matrix( ...           # <--- original

grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix( ...  # <--- new in pandas 0.20.0
        ^^^^^^^^^                      # <--- 9 extra characters
```

I didn't see the benefit of having this minor correction in a separate answer. Why not just put it where it belongs? So that's what I did. I also added a comment explaining the change and for which version of pandas it was applicable.

Once that was done, the new answer had become completely redundant. Not much reason to keep it around. So I flagged it for deletion. This certainly wasn't meant as a sleight to the author or to the undeniable value of his contribution. It was just sound housekeeping.

---

Note: I never flagged it as "low quality", because it certainly isn't low quality.

I did, however, flag it as "not an answer", because in my view, it wasn't an answer proper, but rather a minor correction to an existing answer. That it then had to end up in a queue called "Low Quality Posts" in order to be processed for deletion was admittedly rather misleading on the part of the system. Still, the right thing for reviewers to do, in my view, would have been to vote to delete, for reasons explained above.

Comment: Yeh NAA flags pop them into the LOWQ Q. do you think it might be better to have a comment pointing to the new answer? Or even editing it with a link to the new answer.  I'm thinking that user posted that in good faith and then they lose their rep (which drives the site).

Comment: @YvetteColomb the answer can be deleted and then people will find the updated original answer just fine. That's how the site works. The answerer did indeed post in good faith, but that doesn't mean they should be rewarded for a mistake.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm not sure it's a mistake.

Comment: @AndrasDeak wasn't a mistake, the accepted answer got deprecated.

Comment: @CalvT븃 that answer as-is is a mistake, should've been an edit or a comment. The fact that the accepted answer is deprecated implies that the alternative is writing a full answer altogether. What we currently have is no more than a link-only piece of work.

Comment: Gentle reminder: This is why it's important for users to be able to suggest edits that change the code. If you want to encourage users to edit instead of posting a new answer, please vote [on questions like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of the original reviewers who voted for deletion.

After looking at this again I'm convinced this was the right decision. The update was **not an answer** to the question. It should have been an **edit** to the original answer, preserving the original information of course. Alternatively it could have been a **comment** on the original answer so it could be edited into the answer by the poster (not so good, because comments can always be deleted).

Since I voted the accepted answer has been edited by the person who posted it to include the updated information, which is how it should have been done in the first place.
The update answer has had the code from the original answer added, so it basically duplicates that information. Now I wouldn't vote for deletion because now it is an answer, even if not as complete as the original. But the result is we have two answers with the same information.

I think it's much better to edit answers as APIs change, so that all the relevant information is in one place, instead of one obsolete answer with links to a string of update "answers". For people still using older APIs, that information needs to be kept in the answer as well.