# Should I comment or edit the answer? (new contributor case)

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, new-users

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878562/6487675) to a PHP question. The answer should work, but the post seems a lot like a "code only" answer.

First, I was starting editing the post (wanted to add more explanations and add a link to the formal recommended documentation - which is not changing the answer meaning and complied with [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)) - but then I noticed the OP is "new contributor" (first answer for that user) and I thought, maybe it was best to comment it, so the OP will do that by himself/herself and learn for the next answer he posts.

Should I edit the answer instead? Or was commenting the better action?

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348261/should-i-edit-an-answer-to-add-information-that-is-on-a-comment-of-that-answer), but I am talking specifically about the new contributor case.

Comment: Leaving a comment makes more sense. A *nice* way to get them started on how to do things right. Also, teach a man to fish...

Comment: Why don't you do both? Edit the answer into shape, explaining in a comment why you did that and encourage them to keep your edit in mind when they post their next answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I edit the answer instead? or commenting was the better action?

You have posted a comment, which is - IMHO - sufficient. You can provide a link to the documentation as well. Yet, it is the author's own job to provide the necessary additional information (I usually post-edit my answers with links to documentations and further explanation). If people is going to start to improve other answers with sufficient information, even if it is a new contributor, then it can lead to a bad habit where a person simply posts an low quality, but accurate answer with an expectation that "*someone would improve it later*"...

I know people that would simply just downvote it. I don't like this approach. I saw the answer. It is correct. However, I won't give an upvote because of its quality. If he *did* provide the link to the documentation, then I could give it an upvote.

An other would-be applicable solution is to find a duplicate which has the same problem, but has an informative answer. If you have found one, vote it as a duplicate so that future readers would be led to the other, more informative answer.

Comment: "I usually post-edit my answers with links to documentations and further explanation" This is a risky proposition. I know everyone wants to be the fastest gun in the West, but it's more annoying than anything else to see a dump of code with no explanation. Why not take the time to craft a great answer with the links and explanation and post it all at once? It will likely get more upvotes than others with just code dumps (at least from people like me)...